# Checking which button was clicked by the user before clicking on another button

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to write this, for example. When the user clicks on the button with `id "niekket"` it needs to now the user specifically clicked on that button. After the user has clicked on `"niekket"` and would like to reset the values by clicking on the button with `id "resetbtn"`. `id("uitvoer").innerHTML = // output (a string) depends on which button has been clicked (on niekket or pap) by the user before clicking on the resetbtn` it should output this `alert("You clicked on button niekket") else alert("You clicked on the button pap before clicking on the resetbutton")`

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
function personen(voornaam, achternaam, geboortejaar) {
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    this.achternaam = achternaam;
    this.geboortejaar = geboortejaar;

    this.gegevens = function () {
        return this.voornaam + " " + this.achternaam + " " + this.geboortejaar;
    };

    this.wijzigVoornaam = function (vNaam) {
        this.voornaam = vNaam;
    };

    this.wijzigAchternaam = function (aNaam) {
        this.achternaam = aNaam;
    };
    this.wijzigGeboortejaar = function (jaar) {
        this.geboortejaar = jaar;
    };
}

var niekket = new personen("Niek", "Henk", 1800);
var pap = new personen("Joop", "Freek", 1950);

function id(id) {
    var allId = document.getElementById(id);
    return allId;
}

function allEvents() {
 var idClicked;
    id("niekket").onclick = function () {
        toonGegevens(niekket);
        idClicked = "Niekket";
    };
    id("pap").onclick = function () {
        toonGegevens(pap);
        idClicked = "pap";
    };
    id("resetbtn").onclick = function () {
    id("uitvoer").innerHTML = idClicked;
    };
}
allEvents();

function toonGegevens(p) {
    id("uitvoer").innerHTML = p.gegevens();
}
```

```html
<p id="uitvoer">Klik op de knop en zie deze invoer wijzigen</p>
 <button class="btn" id="niekket">Niekket</button>
 <button class="btn" id="pap">Pap</button>
 <button id="resetbtn">resetbutton</button>
```

Comment: Please include **all** relevant code so that we may reproduce your issue and help to provide a working solution. Include the relevant HTML and CSS. Additionally, please include all the relevant JavaScript as well. Your code references an `id` function, so include that as well.

Comment: Are you asking us how to store a variable?!

Comment: Sounds like you need this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_variables.htm

Comment: Oh damn, easy answer. I got it, was thinking way to difficult I see!

Answer (score 1):

You could store last clicked ID in some variable, like:

```
var lastClickedId;

function allEvents() {
    id("niekket").onclick = function () {
        toonGegevens(niekket);
        lastClickedId = "niekket";
    };
}
```

And then use this `lastClickedId` variable when you need it.